# Cast IntPtr to CWPSTRUCT

Tags: c#, intptr, mouse-hook

In my c# project I’m trying to intercept mouse clicks from another program, but only the ones that come from a certain hwnd as well… I’ve read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761875/is-there-a-way-to-hook-mouse-events-for-a-specific-button-in-a-windows-form) that I can filter my messages using the lParam but I’ve not succeeded to cast it to something I can actually get Hwnd’s back from.

This is how I set up the global mouse hook:

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, s_MouseDelegate, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

I then catch the messages in this function:

```
private static int MouseHookProc(int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
          switch (wParam)
          {
               case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                    mouseDown = true;
                    mouseUp = false;
                    break;
               case WM_LBUTTONUP:
                    mouseUp = true;
                    mouseDown = false;
                    break;
          }
     }
     return CallNextHookEx(s_MouseHookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I then made the CWPSTRUCT like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CWPSTRUCT
{
    public IntPtr lparam;
    public IntPtr wparam;
    public int message;
    public IntPtr hwnd;
}
```

And here's the part where it probably goes wrong...I’ve tried 2 things:

```
CWPSTRUCT cwp = (CWPSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(CWPSTRUCT));
```

Or the unsafe version [this is where I got it from](http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/27/135375.aspx):

```
CWPSTRUCT* cp = (CWPSTRUCT*)lParam;
```

When using the first option I always get 0 for the hwnd part and with the unsafe version I just get nothing... I don’t really know what I’m doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're hooking `WH_MOUSE_LL`, `lParam` contains pointer to [`MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of [`CWPSTRUCT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644964%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which is actually for `WH_CALLWNDPROC`).

So you should define the following structures:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
{
    public POINT pt;
    public int mouseData;
    public int flags;
    public int time;
    public UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}
```

And marshal `lParam` to `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`:

```
MSLLHOOKSTRUCT mouseLowLevelHook = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam,
    typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
```

Also, you should change `wParam`'s type from `int` to `IntPtr`, so it will work properly on 64-bit platforms.

Additional links:

- [Hook Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [LowLevelMouseProc callback function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much! This has solved my problem. I do have 1 small question left... the UIntPtr dwExtraInfo, what exactly does it contain? (Additional information associated with the message.) Because I thought it might be the window where I clicked on? But I don't think it is because it's 0  as well. 

I got the handle of the window I clicked on now by using [WindowFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is that the correct way?

Comment: @VincentC `dwExtraInfo` seems to be a reference to the application-specific extra info.

Comment: @VincentC Yes, you can use [`WindowFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get hwnd. Although it would be better to create a global hook for [`WH_MOUSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644988(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`WH_CALLWNDPROC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644975(v=vs.85).aspx).
You can read about it here: [Using Window Messages to Implement Global System Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18638/Using-Window-Messages-to-Implement-Global-System-H)